# where can I find proof for this lemma

Tags: limits, analysis

My professor gave this lemma but didn't provide the proof also I can't find the proof for this lemma in my books so do you know where I can find prove to this.

if a function $f$ is continuous from the left at a point $γ $ and there exists $δ > 0$ such that $f(x) < 0$ whenever $γ −δ < x < γ$ then $f(γ) ≤ 0$

and

if a function $f$ is continuous from the right at a point $γ $ and $f(γ) < 0$. there exists $δ > 0$ such that $f(x) < 0$ whenever $γ ≤ x < γ +δ.$

Comment: It's literally the definition of limits and continuity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x) < 0 \forall x \in (\gamma - \delta, \gamma)$

Suppose $f(\gamma)>0$

Then if I take $\varepsilon = \frac{f(\gamma)}{2}>0$, there's exists $\delta_{1} >0$ such that

if $\gamma - \delta_{1} < x < \gamma$, then $|f(x) - f(\gamma)| < \varepsilon = \frac{f(\gamma)}{2}$

So, if $\delta_{2} < min\{\delta,\delta_{1}\}$, we have $ \forall x \in (\gamma - \delta_{2}, \gamma)$ that $-\frac{f(\gamma)}{2}< f(x) - f(\gamma) < \frac{f(\gamma)}{2}$ and $f(x) < 0$

Thus $f(\gamma) - \frac{f(\gamma)}{2} < f(x)$ and $f(x) < 0$

So $ 0 < \frac{f(\gamma)}{2} < f(x) < 0$

Absurd!

Then $f(\gamma) \leq 0$

.Second part:

$f(\gamma)<0$ then $-f(\gamma)>0$

So, if I take $\varepsilon = -\frac{f(\gamma)}{2}>0$, there's exist $\delta > 0$

such that if $x \in (\gamma - \delta, \gamma)$ then $|f(x) - f(\gamma)| < -\frac{f(\gamma)}{2}$

Thus $\frac{f(\gamma)}{2}< f(x) - f(\gamma) < -\frac{f(\gamma)}{2}$

So $f(x) < f(\gamma) + -\frac{f(\gamma)}{2}$

Then $f(x) < \frac{f(\gamma)}{2} < 0$.

Then $\forall x$ such that $ \gamma - \delta < x \leq \gamma$, $f(x)<0$

Answer (score 0):

The usual $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition is that

> $f$ is continuous at $\gamma$ if there for every $\epsilon>0$ exist a $\delta>0$ such that $$|x-\gamma|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(\gamma)|<\epsilon$$

Since $f$ is left continuous there exist a $\delta>0$ such that $\gamma-\delta<x<\gamma$ implies $$|f(x)-f(\gamma)|<\epsilon\\f(\gamma)-\epsilon<f(x)<f(\gamma)+\epsilon\tag{1}$$

If you know that $f(x)<0$, what can you conclude from $(1)$?